# VBA sorting causes 9 > 17?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this to sort several columns of numbers in ascending order:

```
With Workbooks(LotWB).Worksheets("SQL Data").Sort
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("J1"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("H1"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("G1"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), Order:=xlAscending
     .SetRange Workbooks(LotWB).Worksheets("SQL Data").Range("A1:AG" & LastRowLot)
     .Header = xlYes
     .Apply
End With
```

But when I run the code, it sorts the numbers in a strange way (e.g. 1, 17, 25, 33, 9).
I know that the numbers are being sorted by the first(leftmost) digit.
What can I do to prevent this faulty sorting?

Comment: The numbers are stored as text.  You will need to convert them to numbers, merely changing the format will not accomplish this.

Comment: @ScottCraner for doing mass conversion, can you do something like `range("A:A") = 1*Range("A:A")` ?

Comment: no, you cannot do that to a variant array in vba.  The best route in my opinion is to loop the columns and use TextToColumns to do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Change Format in Cells Containing Numbers Formatted As Text

- You have to loop through the areas of the range for `.Value = .Value` to work.

**The Code**

```
Const SortColumns As String = "A:A,B:B,G:G,H:H,J:J"
With Workbooks(LotWB).Worksheets("SQL Data")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rng As Range
    With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Set rng = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    End With
    With Intersect(rng, .Range(SortColumns))
        .NumberFormat = 0 ' Choose the number format you need.
        For Each rng In .Areas
            rng.Value = rng.Value
        Next rng
    End With
    With .Sort
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("J1"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("H1"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("G1"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SetRange .Parent.Range("A1:AG" & LastRowLot)
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Scott.

Here's what I used prior to sorting

```
With Workbooks(LotWB).Worksheets("SQL Data").Columns(7)
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: this will not work, as I stated, merely changing the format will not change numbers stored as text into numbers.